# xsd.exe ignores cdata?

Tags: c#, xml, xsd, xml-serialization, xml-deserialization

I used xsd.exe from Microsoft SDKs to first generate a schema of an xml file and then generate a C# file of the previously generated xsd file.
Here is my xml file:

```
<event topic="event.system.visualization.initialization.response" subject="CIBEK204Test0" producer="de.cibek.configurator" timeToLive="0" too="1351252459919" duration="0">
<payload>
    <![CDATA[
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
            <building>
                <floor name="">
                    <location name="Wohnen">
                        <item category="event.environment.apartment.window" groupaddress="10248" location="Wohnen" location.floor="" location.specification="Mitte links"/>
                    </location>
                </floor>
            </building>
    ]]>
</payload>
<properties/>
<traces/>
```

Now the generated xsd:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema id="NewDataSet" xmlns="" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:msdata="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xml-msdata">
<xs:element name="event">
 <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="payload" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="0" />
    <xs:element name="properties" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="1" />
    <xs:element name="traces" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0" msdata:Ordinal="2" />
  </xs:sequence>
  <xs:attribute name="topic" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:attribute name="subject" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:attribute name="producer" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:attribute name="timeToLive" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:attribute name="too" type="xs:string" />
  <xs:attribute name="duration" type="xs:string" />
 </xs:complexType>
 </xs:element>
 <xs:element name="NewDataSet" msdata:IsDataSet="true" msdata:UseCurrentLocale="true">
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:choice minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded">
    <xs:element ref="event" />
  </xs:choice>
</xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

And the generated cs file:

```
using System.Xml.Serialization;

// 
// This source code was auto-generated by xsd, Version=4.0.30319.17929.
// 


/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class @event {

private string payloadField;

private string propertiesField;

private string tracesField;

private string topicField;

private string subjectField;

private string producerField;

private string timeToLiveField;

private string tooField;

private string durationField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string payload {
    get {
        return this.payloadField;
    }
    set {
        this.payloadField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string properties {
    get {
        return this.propertiesField;
    }
    set {
        this.propertiesField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(Form=System.Xml.Schema.XmlSchemaForm.Unqualified)]
public string traces {
    get {
        return this.tracesField;
    }
    set {
        this.tracesField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public string topic {
    get {
        return this.topicField;
    }
    set {
        this.topicField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public string subject {
    get {
        return this.subjectField;
    }
    set {
        this.subjectField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public string producer {
    get {
        return this.producerField;
    }
    set {
        this.producerField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public string timeToLive {
    get {
        return this.timeToLiveField;
    }
    set {
        this.timeToLiveField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public string too {
    get {
        return this.tooField;
    }
    set {
        this.tooField = value;
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlAttributeAttribute()]
public string duration {
    get {
        return this.durationField;
    }
    set {
        this.durationField = value;
    }
}
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class NewDataSet {

private @event[] itemsField;

/// <remarks/>
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("event")]
public @event[] Items {
    get {
        return this.itemsField;
    }
    set {
        this.itemsField = value;
    }
}
}
```

Now my question is: Why does xsd.exe ignore the embedded xml code in CDATA? Is there any possibility to force xsd.exe to NOT ignore CDATA? Or is it possible to generate 2 xsd and cs files and tell the first one (with event in it) that there is a CDATA node that has another xml file in it and link them in the generated code?

Sorry for the long post i hope anyone can help me :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If CDATA is used, the parser ignores everything inside the CDATA section. If your aim is to get the section inside CDATA, please follow this link.

[Getting CDATA XML Section Using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7620434/getting-cdata-xml-section-using-linq)

Answer (score 0):

I successfully deserialize CDATA by using xsd.exe and the following xsd file :

```
<xs:element name="event">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:sequence>
      <xs:element ref="payload" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
    </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:element name="payload">
  <xs:complexType>
    <xs:simpleContent>
      <xs:extension base="xs:string"/>
    </xs:simpleContent>
  </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

The generated code by xsd.exe is :

```
/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class @event {

    private payload[] payloadField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("payload")]
    public payload[] payload {
        get {
            return this.payloadField;
        }
        set {
            this.payloadField = value;
        }
    }
}

/// <remarks/>
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.17929")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType=true)]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlRootAttribute(Namespace="", IsNullable=false)]
public partial class payload {

    private string valueField;

    /// <remarks/>
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTextAttribute()]
    public string Value {
        get {
            return this.valueField;
        }
        set {
            this.valueField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

And using XmlSerializer.Deserialize fill the payload.Value with the CData