# parse CDATA xml

Tags: c#, xml

how do I get value in CDATA?

What I have:
it's string I would like parse it and get value like NOM_VAG and other

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1251"?>
<GetInformReply><Inform_ID>-14</Inform_ID><ASOUPReply>
<![CDATA[<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?>
<S:Envelope xmlns:S="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
<S:Body>
<ns2:getReferenceSPV4664Response xmlns:ns2="http://service.siw.pktbcki.rzd/">
<return><referenceSPV4664><row><NOM_VAG>75142901</NOM_VAG><ROD_VAG_UCH>70</ROD_VAG_UCH><KOD_SOB>20</KOD_SOB><DATE_NACH xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><STAN_NACH>0</STAN_NACH><DOR_NACH>0</DOR_NACH><STR_NACH>0</STR_NACH><DATE_KON xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><STAN_NAZN>612003</STAN_NAZN><DOR_NAZN>61</DOR_NAZN><STR_NAZN>643</STR_NAZN><GRUZPOL>4232</GRUZPOL><GRUZPOL_OKPO>0000000000</GRUZPOL_OKPO>
</row></referenceSPV4664><amount>1</amount><amountRF>1</amountRF><amountNotRF>0</amountNotRF><codeTypeObject>1</codeTypeObject><returnCode>0</returnCode><errorCode>0</errorCode><errorMessage xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/><title>Справка о дислокации вагона</title><dateIzm xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:nil="true"/></return></ns2:getReferenceSPV4664Response></S:Body>
</S:Envelope>
]]>
 </ASOUPReply></GetInformReply>
```

I need to parse xml between CDATA

```
What I did:
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.LoadXml(xmlText);
XmlElement xRoot = xDoc.DocumentElement;
xRoot.GetElementsByTagName("<![CDATA[]]>");
foreach (XmlNode item in xRoot)
    {
        if (item.LocalName == "ASOUPReply")
    {
        XmlNode attr = item.Attributes.GetNamedItem("row");
        foreach (var itemXMl in ((System.Xml.XmlCharacterData)item.LastChild).Data)
        {
                            
        }
return xmlText;
```

UPD:
this works

```
public void pp (string text)
        {
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(text);
            var soapResponse = xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "row").Select(x => new SPR4664()
            {
                NOM_VAG = (string)x.Element(x.Name.Namespace + "NOM_VAG"),
                ROD_VAG_UCH = (string)x.Element(x.Name.Namespace + "ROD_VAG_UCH"),
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

model:

```
public class SPR4664
    {
        public string NOM_VAG { get; set; }
        public string ROD_VAG_UCH { get; set; }

    }
```

but I have about 30 rows.
Do I have to write everyone manually?
[Link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x8hyR.png)

Comment: OMG XML inside CDATA inside XML

Comment: this is like a dream within a dream

Comment: Looks like a duplicate of [Getting CDATA XML Section Using Linq](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7620434/3744182), agree?

Comment: A nightmare within a nightmare even

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public void pp (string text)
        {
            XDocument xml = XDocument.Parse(text);
            var soapResponse = xml.Descendants().Where(x => x.Name.LocalName == "row").Select(x => new SPR4664()
            {
                NOM_VAG = (string)x.Element(x.Name.Namespace + "NOM_VAG"),
                ROD_VAG_UCH = (string)x.Element(x.Name.Namespace + "ROD_VAG_UCH"),
            }).FirstOrDefault();
        }
```

model:

```
public class SPR4664
    {
        public string NOM_VAG { get; set; }
        public string ROD_VAG_UCH { get; set; }

    }
```

it works.

Answer (score 1):

Select the `ASOUPReply` element node, read out its `InnerText`, feed it to a second `XmlDocument`s `LoadXml` method (you might need to eliminate any white space preceding the XML declaration), then select the `NOM_VAG` element.